# Java - Retrieving nested JSON array key values

Tags: java, arrays, json

I've got a JSON response that looks like this:

```
USER:[{
   "id":"145454",
   "name":"JJones",
   "patientInfo":"[{"id":"12334", "doctor":"Smith"}]",
   "insurance":true,
   "caregiverName":"Jones"
}]
```

I'm trying to create a java method so I can access the key value pairs of the nested `JSONArray`. For example I don't want the entire JSON array I just want to retrieve the **doctor** name from the `patientInfo` JSON array. Any ideas how I would do this in Java I'm completely stuck here.

This is sudo code but I imagine it would be something like:

```
String doctorInfo() {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(user)
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("patientInfo")

    String doctor = arr.getValue("doctor")
}
```

And I'd like to be able to access it on the front end by doing

```
doctorInfo().doctor
```

Code samples are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will be like this:

```
String doctorInfo(String jsonString) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString)
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("patientInfo")
    JSONObject patientJSONObject = arr.getJSONObject(0);
    String doctor = patientJSONObject.getString("doctor");
    return doctor;
}
```

The above code sample assumes you are passing the below string as the parameter.

> {    "id":"145454",    "name":"JJones",
>   "patientInfo":"[{"id":"12334", "doctor":"Smith"}]",
>   "insurance":true,    "caregiverName":"Jones" }